# Output HTML 5 Data Atribute via Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to output data-id attributes of each link once clicked, but because both links have same href attrbutes so my jquery selector is only showing 'yahoo' which is attribute of first link. Any better ideas ?

```
<a href="#test" data-id="yahoo">yahoo.co.uk</a>
<a href="#test" data-id="google">Google.co.uk</a>

console.log($("a[href$='#test']").data('id'));
```

Comment: why do they have the same href?

Comment: don't know why ? but is there a better solution ?

Comment: Yeah, maybe just give them all a common class? Cuz its unlikely that they will share the same href in real life....example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `click` handler.  The `this` reference will be the dom element that was clicked.

```
<script>
   $("a[href='#test']").click(function(e) {
      // DOM element --> jQuery element
      var el = $(this);
      console.log(el.data('id'));
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   });
</script>
```

Comment: It works, can another 'word' be added to console... i tried something like console.log('new word' + el.data('id'));   but than it outputs all links at once..

Comment: that should work; the `data` method returns a string so that should be standard string concatenation... see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shanonvl/pAjSp/

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get the `data-id` of *all* elements with `href="#test"`? In that case you would be able to do:

```
$('a[href="#test"]').map(function() { return $(this).data('id'); });
```

Comment: While this is helpful :) the OP specifically stated ....'get id of each link once CLICKED'

Comment: I did miss that. Well this answer is entirely irrelevant then.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($("a[href$='#test']").data('id'));
```

will give only the first occurance

try this

```
$("a[href$='#test']").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('id')); 
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/kGRVu/

Comment: your solution outputs all links at once rather than each link individually

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here you go...

```
$("a[href^='#test']").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log($(this).data('id'));

});
```

But its unlikely your links will actually have the same href...so I would just give them a common class as a selector...

```
 <a href="www.google.com" class="link" data-id="google">Google</a>
```

And then access that class....

```
$("a.link").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: it outputs an extra link with every new click

Comment: yes,the second solution via adding a link class works. but i was more thinking in terms not amending the html. The other solution of accessing the dom via el ref seems to works. Thank you :)